# why this map surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that a homomorphism from a field onto a ring with more than one
> element must be an isomorphism.

This is what my textbook's solution:
Assume $\phi : F \to R$ is a homomorphism which is onto and $R$ has more than one
element. By the First Isomorphism Theorem we know $F/Ker \phi \cong R$. In a field $F$ the only
ideals are $\{0\}$ and $F$ itself thus Ker $\phi$ is one of these. If Ker $\phi$ $= \{F\}$ then the FIT gives $F/F\cong R$ or $\{0\} \cong R$, impossible since $R$ has more than one element. Thus Ker $\phi = \{0\}$ and the FIT gives $F/\{0\} \cong R$ given by $x + \{0\} \mapsto \phi(x)$ being an isomorphism. Thus $\phi$  is.
I don't understand why $\phi$ is surjective? Can anyone explain ?

Comment: What does "$x + \{0\} \mapsto \phi$" mean? $\phi$ is a map.

Comment: Hi, it might be a spelling issue, but the problem says "from a field onto a ring", which, in a mathematical sense, means surjectivity. But the confusing part is that in the very first line of the proof it says "Assume $\phi$ is onto" with no further explanation

Answer (score 3):

The map $\phi$ is surjective by assumption. The word "onto" simply means surjective. Otherwise the FIT would not work here either since we only have $F/\text{Ker}(\phi) \cong \text{Im}(\phi)$ in general.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If the word "onto" isn't given this meaning in this context, the standard inclusion homomorphism from the field of real numbers to the ring of real polynomials would be an immediate counterexample. Or any trivial homomorphism.